# Mockito mocking Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, mockito-scala

*When unit testing, what is the best approach to mocking out Akka Streams calls involving Sources, Flows and Sinks?*

---

For example, the [`takeWhile`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/takeWhile.html) function:

```
def takeWhile(p: Out => Boolean): Repr[Out]
```

Where [`Repr`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/4e670553021a859b55ba2b1606ef1ae5ba2369bf/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.scala#L750) is a trait within a trait:

```
trait FlowOps[+Out, +Mat] {
  import akka.stream.impl.Stages._
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  type Repr[+O] <: FlowOps[O, Mat] {
    type Repr[+OO] = FlowOps.this.Repr[OO]
    type Closed = FlowOps.this.Closed
  }
```

If an object under test calls something like: `mySource.takeWhile( ... ).runWith( ... )` I might need to mock it out...

How do you work out how to mock out, e.g., `mock[Source[Any, Any]].takeWhile(*) returns mock[?]`

The interactions between `Source`, `Repr`, `FlowOps`, and `Out` are unclear to me.

The source code for the `FlowOps` trait [warns](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/4e670553021a859b55ba2b1606ef1ae5ba2369bf/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.scala#L740) that it is internal and that one should not derive from it...does this affect mocking it?

Comment: Why would it be required to mock stream? I guess that's easier to just create test stream from pure values/fixtures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to mock anything for basic tests with Akka Streams components; just use the [testkit](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-testkit.html). For inspiration, check out [the tests in the Akka repository](https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/v2.5.26/akka-stream-tests/src/test/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl). Here is an example from the [`FlowTakeWhileSpec`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.26/akka-stream-tests/src/test/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/FlowTakeWhileSpec.scala):

```
"take while predicate is true" in assertAllStagesStopped {
  Source(1 to 4).takeWhile(_ < 3).runWith(TestSink.probe[Int]).request(3).expectNext(1, 2).expectComplete()
}
```